# Writing path-dependent conditional expectation in terms of distribution

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $x$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable, then for any bounded and continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ one may write
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)\pi(x)dx,
$$
where $\pi$ is the density of the law of $X$ *(granted that it exists)*.

In general, if $f:C([0,T];\mathbb{R})$ is a continuous map to $\mathbb{R}$; then given an $\mathbb{R}$-valued process $X_t$ one can view $f(X_{\cdot})(\omega)$ as a random-variable (defined path-by-path).  Is there way to write
$$
E[f(X_{\cdot})] = \int_{t=0}^T \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(\cdot) ...\pi_t(x)dxdt?
$$
Or something similar (without integrating over the path-space directly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. In general, to find $Ef(X_\cdot)$, you need to know the distribution of the entire path $X_\cdot\,$. So, as a minimum, you need to know the so-called finite-dimensional distributions of the process $X_\cdot$, that is, the joint distributions of the random variables $X_{t_1},\dots,X_{t_k}$ for any $t_1,\dots,t_k$ in $[0,T]$ -- whereas the densities $\pi_t$ determine only the individual distributions of the $X_t$'s for $t\in[0,T]$.